# How to test the IO speed on Android?

Tags: android, io, adb, sd-card, android-sdcard

I am debugging a slaggy phone: Galaxy Nexus.

Can I use ADB to test IO speed of it? Or grep some info about related information, like SD card model?

Comment: Do you wish to test the speed of ADB or of the storage device?

Answer (score 0):

Pushing a large file will give you some speed stats in the end.

```
3199 KB/s (111387 bytes in 0.034s)
```

Comment: Yes, but what do you believe is the determining factor of that speed - adb or the storage media?

Comment: It should be a combination of usb port speed, mother board limitations and sd card storage. I am not good enough in hardware to know the limitation factor. I don't think SOF is the right place to ask for this.

Comment: A major potential factor you are overlooking is the possibility of inefficiency in the ADB transfer protocol itself - just because the hardware has a theoretic capability doesn't mean the software is able to fully utilize it.

Comment: That's possible, but I really doubt that appart a handshake adb can really slow down a binary file transfer.

Comment: Good point @ChrisStratton, you even make me doubt a generic software can get the most of each hardware. I guess it depends a lot of manufacturers's android/linux kernel device drivers.

Comment: My experience has been that it substantially did, at least in the past.  In fact, software often has to be very carefully written if it is going to get peak performance from hardware, especially where communication between processors is concerned.  Even today, I get only trivially faster results pushing to /dev/null (ie, no media involved) than to the emulated SD card, and still well below what USB should be capable of.

Comment: It's not necessarily the kernel or drivers either.  Try transferring to the same phone via MTP or USB Mass Storage and you may well find it faster than ADB.

Comment: Funny, I would never have said that. Any speed benchmark ?